# Let $U, V$ be vectors. $|U|=5, V$ is unitary & angle between $U$ and $V$ is $\frac{\pi}{6}$, find scalar $λ$ such that $U+λV$ is orthogonal to $U$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

> Let $U, V$ be vectors in some vector space. If $|U|=5$, then $V$ is unitary and the angle between $U$ and $V$ is $\frac{\pi}{6}$, find the scalar $\lambda$ such that $U+\lambda V$ is orthogonal to $U$.

I know that the dot product  $U\cdot V$ is $4.33$ because $|5|\cdot|1|\cos(\frac{\pi}6)= U\cdot V$

How to proceed? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: already edit please help me bro

Comment: Hints:  The dot product of two vectors that are orthogonal (perpendicular) is zero:  $ \ U \ \bullet \ (U + \lambda V) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  The dot product distributes over addition.

Comment: Nice Editing @VOZESTOICA. Now, $U+\lambda V$ is orthogonal to $U$, means perpendicular. Hence, angle between them would be $90^\circ$. Their dot product will be zero. Try forming equation and proceed this way.

Comment: U ∙ (U+λV) = 0 then λ=-(u.u/u.v) how ever I dont have the vector u just the magnitude of |u|

Comment: Yes, and you  know  _both_ of those products...  You don't need the components of either vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\vec{U}+\lambda \vec{V}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{U}$. Hence, angle between them will be $90^\circ$.

Thus, $(\vec{U}+\lambda \vec{V})\cdot \vec{U}$ will be

> $0\\ \\\text{(because $\cos 90^\circ=0$)}$

Hence,
$|U|^2 + \lambda (\vec{U}\cdot\vec{V})=0$
(Dot Product is commutative, and $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}=|x|^2$)

Thus, $$\lambda=-\frac{|U|^2 }{|U||V|\cos\frac{\pi}{6}}$$

Putting Values  $$\lambda=-\frac{25}{5\cdot 1\cdot \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}}$$

Thus, $$\boxed{\lambda=-5.7735}$$